# VectorTileSource is not rendering features from Geojson in a right way

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

For some reason I am not able to see the features in the map in a right way. Even if I dont get any error in console.
I also can confirm that I am receiving features for each tille in console. When i zoom and set the stroke of the feature  to 100 than I see some lines but not in the right place. My initial idea is that there is something wrong with projections but not sure what.

code:

```
var view = new View({
     center: berlin,
     zoom: 6,
    });

var styleFunction = function (feature) { return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()]; };

var vector_source  = new VectorTileSource({
        tileSize: 256,
        url: "some-url/{z}/{x}/{y}",
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        tileLoadFunction: async function(tile, url) {

                //var pro = map.getView().getProjection();

                var format = new GeoJSON({featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()});
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const data = await response.json();
                const features = format.readFeatures(data);
                tile.setFeatures(features);

         },
      
    });


var tile_layer = new VectorTileLayer({
         source: vector_source,
         visibility: true,
         style: styleFunction,
         maxZoom: 24,
       });


 var map = new Map({
    layers: [ new TileLayer({ source: new OSM(), }),new TileLayer({ source: new TileDebug(),}), tile_layer],
    target: 'map',
    view: view, 
  });
```

Comment: If you have standard EPSG:4326 geojson coordinates you should not need a tileLoadFunction just let it default similar to the topojson example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/osm-vector-tiles.html  Otherwise I suggest you specify both the data and feature projections as options on the readFeatures call instead of on the format constructor.  If the geojson uses tile pixels units similar to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson-vt.html you will also need to specify the tile extent.

Comment: Is there a way to check whats the geojson standard of the endpoind ?

Comment: Open one of the tiles as text.  If the coordinates are in the range [-180, -90] to [180, 90] it will be EPSG:4326, Tile pixels are typically in the range 0 to 4000, much larger values would suggest EPSG:3857 or a national projection.

Comment: @Mike at first thanks for your comments. This is what i am able to see when it comes to the tile:
extent: (4) [3757032.814272985, 6887893.4928338025, 4383204.949985148, 7514065.628545966]
features_: []
format_: null
interimTile: null
listeners_: {change: Array(1)}
ol_uid: "80"
projection: EPSG3857Projection {code_: "EPSG:3857", units_: "m", extent_: Array(4), worldExtent_: Array(4), axisOrientation_: "enu", …}
resolution: 2445.98490512564
state: 2
tileCoord: (3) [6, 38, 20]
tileLoadFunction_: ƒ tileLoadFunction(_x, _x2)

Comment: And these are coordinates for a given feature: [13.38537086, 52.61600151]
 [13.385263, 52.61499577]
 [13.38512047, 52.61476656]
 [13.37905705, 52.60635132], which is a stringLine obviousely